# Require JS recommending keeping all inline javascript out of the html - reasonable?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

When we [read on the require JS page](http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html#add) we can read:

> To take full advantage of the optimization tool, 
>   it is  suggested that you keep all inline script out of the HTML,  and only reference
>   require.js with a require call like so to load your script

Well, ok right, very funny. What about things like field IDs that we only know on the screen?
Say I return 1000 rows of an sql, and need a function for a row entry, whose ID I got on the view, but not otherwise?

Let's just throw in a PHP variable

```
<script>myFancyJSfunction( <?php echo $sqlRow[3] ?>);</script>
```

**EDIT** I mean it must not even be a variable, it can as well be a hard coded variable like this

```
<script>myFancyJSfunction( "idWhichIsOnlyCorrectOnThisScreen");</script>
```

How am I supposed to keep this inline javascript out of the html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, by putting inline JSON

*** Off the cuff, syntax may be slightly off, but the process works ***

You may want to properly encode the value, depending.  This is the simple example.

```
<script type="application/json" id="myvars">
{
   "inlineParam": "<?php echo $sqlRow[3] ?>"
}
</script>
```

Then, in your module:

```
var globals = JSON.parse($("#myvars").text());
myFancyJSfunction(globals.inlineParam);
```

Comment: It's not -- one of the brilliant folks on my team discovered it.

Comment: would be cool to define whole javascript functions. But json doesn't like line breaks, bit sad. Possibility is to actually use plain javascript and `" +` for newlines. Then use eval to execute the string. Yeah omg the god forsaken eval. Imho: Whatever works.

Comment: No need for the json roundtrip. Just set a global variable on the page

Comment: @Munter -- That's the point.  You *can't* set a global variable on the page because the parse strips all JavaScript out.

Comment: What parsing? r.js? Sounds quite buggy to me. Use a better bundling tool